# Why is "Absolute Space and Time" thread closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen

I'm interested in the thread [Do absolute space and time exist?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/371315). But at the beginning of that thread is the statement "closed 2 years ago"? Does that mean you can no longer post comments? Can you reactivate the thread by posting the same question again? The thread certainly deserves more answers!

Answer (score 7):

As the banner at the top says, that question was closed because a similar question, [Is spacetime absolute?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/183577/44126), was already asked and already had satisfactory answers.

Note that our community is based on asking questions and getting answers, not on having discussions.  If you post exactly the same question again, the community will probably vote to close it as another duplicate, unless you are explicit about how the existing question and its existing answers don't meet your needs.  If you just want to shoot the breeze about things that interest you, there are other places on the internet to do that (one of which is [our chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar)).

I suggest you [take the site tour](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a better idea of how we do things here. Welcome!

Answer (score 5):

It's possible to post comments on the closed question [Do absolute space and time exist?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/371315/123208)  but you don't have the 50 reputation points required to [comment everywhere](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) (although you can comment on your own answers or questions, or any answers to your own questions).

Stack Exchange sites are not discussion forums, and the Q&A (question & answer) pages here do *not* work like the threads on such forums. Sometimes the comments on a page can develop into a discussion, but that is not encouraged: comments should be used to request clarification or suggest improvements to a question or answer.

If you do have a new question on this topic which you'd like to ask, you are welcome to do so, but please make sure first that it isn't answered in the existing Q&A pages on this topic.

If you want to have a discussion  on physics topics, there are some [chat rooms](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat) attached to the site. The main Physics.SE chat room is [The h bar](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar). You only need 20 rep points to post in chat.